# How to dynamically add waypoints in Angular along with auto complete address?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ngmodel

```
<div [hidden]="!showWaypoint" #waypoint>
                <div class="form-group label-floating">
                  <label class="control-label">Waypoint</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control search-address" name = "waypoint" placeholder=" " [(ngModel)]="wayPointInput" #stop>
                </div>
              </div>
```

I want to clone this entire portion, just like appending when i am clicking on add waypoint. I Dont want to use structural directives like *ngFor.
I have also consoled this

```
 @ViewChild('waypoint') wp;
    console.log(this.wp.nativeElement);
```

but I dont know how to append it along with the change in ngModel name so that after submitting I get a set of data in an array.

Comment: can you please explain why such requirement?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your ask, but this looks like a case for `ngTemplate`: https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet

Comment: @Plochie https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir///@12.9697259,77.7178782,13z/data=!5m1!1e2

Just like this where I can add stops in between

Comment: I dont understant the google maps links. Also you cant just clone the template. The most you can do is clone the dom generated by template ref. But in that case you will not be getting any angular features anyway.

Comment: I want to add waypoints
which is nothing but a textbox along with auto complete address